# I can't update kernel

Tags: kernel, updates, repository, gnupg

I'm trying to update kernel due to instructions in this site https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

I installed 5.4.12 kernel from kernel.org and 5.4.12 key.

```
user:~$ gpg --verify linux-5.4.12.tar.sign

gpg: assuming signed data in 'linux-5.4.12.tar'
gpg: Signature made Sal 14 Oca 2020 22:09:38 +03
gpg:                using RSA key 647F28654894E3BD457199BE38DBBDC86092693E
gpg: Good signature from "Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@kernel.org>" [unknown]
gpg:                 aka "Greg Kroah-Hartman (Linux kernel stable release signing key) <greg@kroah.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 647F 2865 4894 E3BD 4571  99BE 38DB BDC8 6092 693E

user:~$ gpg --recv keys 647F28654894E3BD457199BE38DBBDC86092693E

gpg: "keys" not a key ID: skipping
gpg: key 38DBBDC86092693E: 179 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 38DBBDC86092693E: "Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

why this is happens? I've tried about days to update a kernel but there is always an error. why is my ubuntu has lots of problems I don't know.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, but the 5.4 kernel is currently only supported on *development* or *testing* releases (eg. Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: ubuntu 19.10 version 5.3.26 kernel. I heard 5.3 has frozen issues that I experienced. So, I see 5.4.12 stable version then I decided to update to see if my frozen issues has gone or not,